# How to get the value of a stored procedure OUTPUT variable

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I have a simple SQL Server stored procedure that accepts an input parameter and sets an output parameter. The essence of the stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROC SomeDB.dbo.SomeProc
    @input varchar(255),
    @output int OUTPUT
AS
    IF @input = 'a'
    BEGIN
        SET @output = 0;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @output = 1;
    END
    ;
GO
```

I want to get the value of the `@output` variable in PowerShell. If I were to do this in SSMS, I would do something like:

```
DECLARE @out int;
EXEC SomeDB.dbo.SomeProc 'a', @out OUTPUT;
PRINT @out;
```

But, I don't think it's that straightforward in PowerShell.

Here is my script so far in PowerShell (which I know is incomplete):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$server = "some_IP_address"
$db = "SomeDB"
$input = "'a'"
$query = "EXEC dbo.SomeProc $input;"

try {
  Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $db -Query $query -QueryTimeout 60000
} catch {
  Write-Host "stored proc error"
}
```

How do I get the value of the `@output` variable in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
$cn = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$cn.ConnectionString = '...'
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = 'dbo.SomeProc'
$cmd.Connection = $cn
$cmd.CommandType = [Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure

$p = $cmd.Parameters.Add('@output', '')
$p.Direction = [Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
$p.Size = 42

$cn.Open()
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$p.SqlValue.Value
```

[[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/015f3ceb-bec3-4b15-9bd2-25f50058ce0e)]