# Powershell using System.Data.SqlDBType varbinary

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ado

I'm trying to import a ZIP-File from a SQL-Server. The column in der SQL-table is defined as varbinary(max). I'm using a SQL-stored procedure with an output parameter giving me this zip-file.
I defined (see code) an cmd.parameter (system.data.sqldbtype::varbinary,-1) , "-1" should be the "max"-length, but I get no records back ($rd.HasRecords is null..).

Thanks for your help.

```
    Function Get-SQLData
    {
        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=XXXX\YYYY;Database=SQL_XXX;Integrated Security=no;User=SQLServer_XX;Password=xxYYYY"
        $conn.Open() | out-null
        $cmd = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand #("deployment.getZIPFile", $conn)
        #Proz
        $cmd.Connection = $conn
        $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $cmd.CommandText = "deployment.getZIPFile"
        #### Proz-Parameter
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@file_typ",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar,5) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@file_typ'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@file_typ'].value = 'PS' 
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@domain",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar,5) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@domain'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@domain'].value = ($env:USERDNSDOMAIN).Split('.')[0] # domain
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@serverName",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar,50) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@serverName'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@serverName'].value = $env:COMPUTERNAME #local server
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@scriptVersion",[system.data.SqlDbType]::decimal) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@scriptVersion'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@ScriptVersion'].Precision=18 
        $cmd.Parameters['@ScriptVersion'].Scale=2
        $cmd.Parameters['@scriptVersion'].value = $MyVersion
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@operatingSystem",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 100) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@operatingSystem'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@operatingSystem'].value = (gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem).caption 
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@serverTyp",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 50) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@serverTyp'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@serverTyp'].value = $serverTyp
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@serverSubTyp",[system.data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 50) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@serverSubTyp'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        $cmd.Parameters['@serverSubTyp'].value = $serverSubTyp
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@aktScriptVersion",[system.data.SqlDbType]::decimal) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@aktScriptVersion'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Output
        $cmd.Parameters['@aktScriptVersion'].Precision=18 
        $cmd.Parameters['@aktScriptVersion'].Scale=2
        #
        $cmd.Parameters.Add("@ZIPFile",[system.data.SqlDbType]::varbinary,-1) | out-Null
        $cmd.Parameters['@ZIPFile'].Direction = [system.data.ParameterDirection]::Output
        #### Proz-Parameter Ende
        #$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() #| out-null ## org
        $rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader() # gibt es Records?
        #$rd = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        if ($rd.HasRows) # gibt es Records?
        {
            $bufferSize = 8192
            # Stream Lesen..
            # Create a byte array for the stream.            
            $out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)             
            # Looping through records            
            While ($rd.Read())            
            {    
                
                $fileLocation = "C:\PerfLogs\XXXX\ZIPImport.7z"      
                #Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetInt32(0));                    
                # New BinaryWriter            
                $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $fileLocation,'Create','Write';           
                $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs;            
               
                $start = 0;            
                # Read first byte stream            
                $received = $rd.GetBytes(0, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);      ## 1     
                While ($received -gt 0)            
                {            
                   $bw.Write($out, 0, $received);            
                   $bw.Flush();            
                   $start += $received;            
                   # Read next byte stream            
                   $received = $rd.GetBytes(0, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);   ## 1         
                }            
            
                $bw.Close();            
                $fs.Close();            
            }            
            # Closing & Disposing all objects            
            $fs.Dispose()           
            $rd.Close()            
            $cmd.Dispose()            
            $conn.Close()            
            Write-Output ("ZIP-Import Finished")
            # 7z Sektion
            $unzip = 'C:\PerfLogs\xxxx\Modul'
            & ${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe x $fileLocation "-o$($unzip)" -y
            Write-Output ("UNZIP Finished")
        } 
        $conn.Close()
        $conn.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: An Out parameter for a stored procedure is not the same thing as a returned record. When you execute the procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, what happens?

Comment: when I execute the stored procedure locally with Management Studio (SQL-Server) and define an output parameter type: varbinary(max) it works perfectly. It must be the problem with cmd.Parameter system.data.sqldbtype::varbinary, -1. There is no "max", on the MS-page is stated: -1. I can execute perfectly any other stored procedure with a diffrent output typ (int, var etc.) works nice.

Comment: No. You're trying to write an `SqlDataReader` called `$rd` to file. This cannot work. An `SqlDataReader` reads records, not bytes. It does not magically know that you actually want to read binary data from the `@ZIPFile` parameter. If your stored procedure does not produce records (and it seems that way) then `$rd.HasRows` will always be false. You need to read from the parameter instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of a stored procedure OUTPUT variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670543/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-stored-procedure-output-variable)

Comment: Output parameters in PowerShell are no different than in any other .NET language. You have to consume any rows from the statement before you try to access the output parameter's value, or use ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: when I don't use a stored procedure it works just fine! 
I put the code in the main question.
So it must be the parameter: system.data.sqldbtype::varbinary,-1

Comment: You're not listening. It's not the parameter type.

Comment: 1. $rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader() is already here empty.
2. $rd = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is empty as well.
3. when I don't use the stored procedure: 
$cmd.CommandText = "Select [datafile] from deployment.softwarerepository where id = 2"
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader() gets me the zip file back, means the variable $rd is not empty!

Comment: I'm using many different stored procedures with an output parameter (but not varbinary!) using the same code like above and it works, so it must be the parameter varbinary, -1?

Comment: You're not listening. `$rd` is not a byte array. It's not empty, but you can't write it to file. Read the duplicate thread. Think about my earlier comment once more.

Comment: @Purclot, add the proc code to your question for clarity. The value can be retrieved immediately after calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` with `$cmd.Parameters["@ZIPFile"].Value`. The parameter value will be `[System.DBNull]::Value` if no row was found.

Comment: @Dan: when I start: $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() then $cmd.Parameters["@ZIPFile"] gives the output I need. So Tomalak was right saying it's not about system.data.sqldbtype::varbinary, -1.
Now the problem is how to read this file (it's a zipped folder-structure)..till now I was using (see above my procedure):
if ($rd.HasRows).....it doesn't work obviosly theh $cmd.Parameter has type "SqlParameter" and $rd should be Datareader..

Comment: You do not need `if ($rd.HasRows)` and a `While ($rd.Read()) ` loop to process the zip file output parameter. Once you have the value, execute the code inside the `while` loop once.

Comment: @Dan: but still I do need: 
$fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $fileLocation,'Create','Write';           
$bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs; don't I?
Or how could I read the whole imput from $cmd.Parameter["@zipfile"] into the variable:
$fileLocation = "C:\PerfLogs\Admin\ZIPImport.7z"  ?

Comment: @Purclot, one way is with this one-liner: `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\ZIPImport.7z", $cmd.Parameters["@ZIPFile"].Value)`

Comment: @Dan: this done the trick! Thanks a lot! The one-liner with [System.IO.File] is so easy and elegant..I wonder why should I even use the method with BinaryWriter (see my code, which I found on internet)..?

Comment: @Tomalak: sorry, I put my question wrongly, my fault, thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments that solved your problem, the parameters in your question are correct. The issue is with the code that executes the procedure and processes the result.

There is no need to use a `SqlDataReader` here because the proc returns the value in an output parameter instead of in a result set column. Also, since the entire byte array is returned, it is much easier to write the value directly to the file rather than in a read/write loop.

Below is one way to write the output parameter byte array to a file.

```
# execute the proc, returning the @ZIPFile output parameter
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | out-null
if($cmd.Parameters["@ZIPFile"].Value -eq [System.DBNull]::Value) {
    Write-Output "Zipfile not found in database"
}
else {
    # write the byte arrary output value to a file
    $fileLocation = "C:\PerfLogs\XXXX\ZIPImport.7z"      
    Write-Output "Exporting $($cmd.Parameters["@ZIPFile"].Value.Length) bytes to $fileLocation"
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($fileLocation, $cmd.Parameters["@ZIPFile"].Value)
}
```